# if else function issue?

Tags: php, while-loop, if-statement

I have the following code with the if...else statement within a while loop.

```
$colour = array("50305A", "E33600", "DBDD02", "73BE58");
$nextcolr = next($colour);
 if ($nextcolr == FALSE)
 {
    reset($colour);
    echo current($colour);
 }
 else
 {
    echo next($colour);
 }
```

I can't work out why what ever is in the else statement isn't being executed, even if I switch the two statements and reverse the operator.  Could anyone help me?

The entire while loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "by <a href='/neuro/profile.php?userid=$row[MemberID]'>" . $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'] . "</a> on " . $row['Timestamp'] . " | " . $row['NumberOfComments'] . " comments.";
  echo "<div id='blog' style='background-color:#";
  if ($nextcolr == FALSE)
    {
    reset($colour);
    echo current($colour);
    }
  else
    {
    echo next($colour);
    }
  echo "'><a href='blog.php?threadid=" . $row['tID'] . "'>" . $row['Title'] . "</a></div>";
  }
```

Comment: Here is the entire while loop:

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo "by <a href='/neuro/profile.php?userid=$row[MemberID]'>" . $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'] . "</a> on " . $row['Timestamp'] . " | " . $row['NumberOfComments'] . " comments.";
   echo "<div id='blog' style='background-color:#";
   if ($nextcolr == FALSE)
  {
  echo next($colour);
  }
   else
  {
  reset($colour);
  echo current($colour);
  }
   echo "'><a href='blog.php?threadid=" . $row['tID'] . "'>" . $row['Title'] . "</a></div>";
   echo "Tags:<br /><hr />";
   }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$colour = array("50305A", "E33600", "DBDD02", "73BE58");
while ... {
    $nextcolr = next($colour);
    if ($nextcolr === FALSE)
    {
        reset($colour);
    }
    echo current($colour);
}
```

is how your while loop should look like. If I am right, you are also defining $colour in the while loop, which might cause problems.

Comment: No, only the if...else statement is within the loop.

Comment: Also, you should use === instead of == on the first `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

If all this is in the while loop, then you are re-declaring the array on each iteration, thus returning the array internal pointer to the beginning with each iteration.

Comment: No, only the if...else statement is within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate this array multiple times, you could do it this way:

```
 $colour = array("50305A", "E33600", "DBDD02", "73BE58");
 $i = 0;

 while ... {
    ...
    echo $colour[$i++ % count($colour)];
    ...
 }
```

So you don't need this if-else block.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your original while loop is that you never change the value of $nextcolr.
Thus, it always remains FALSE and the else part never gets executed.